# RSVP on Cisco, Understanding and basic configuration

Tags: cisco, qos

I'm looking for some help about a basic configuration and use of RSVP QoS into a Cisco router (2901 series).
Since I have no luck using RSVP into my main network, I have tried to make it work in a basic configuration but with no positive result so far. Here is my basic network:

```
123.22.1.2_____                                         ____123.22.2.2
               |_____123.22.1.10 Router 123.22.2.20____|
123.22.1.3_____|                                       |____123.22.2.3
```

My priority flow comes from 123.22.2.2 to 123.22.1.2.
So I have the following configuration on my router (inspired by this [webpage](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios/12_2/qos/configuration/guide/fqos_c/qcfrsvp.html)):

`version 15.2
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname R3
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
no aaa new-model
!
ip cef
!
no ipv6 cef
multilink bundle-name authenticated
!
license udi pid … sn …
!
interface Embedded-Service-Engine0/0
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 ip address 123.22.1.10 255.255.255.0
 duplex auto
 speed 10
 ip rsvp bandwidth 7500 7500
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 ip address 123.22.2.20 255.255.255.0
 duplex auto
 speed 10
 ip rsvp bandwidth 1 1
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/0
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/2
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/3
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
ip forward-protocol nd
!
no ip http server
no ip http secure-server
!
control-plane
!
line con 0
line aux 0
line 2
 no activation-character
 no exec
 transport preferred none
 transport output pad telnet rlogin lapb-ta mop udptn v120 ssh
 stopbits 1
line vty 0 4
 login
 transport input all
!
scheduler allocate 20000 1000
!
end`

And after the reservation is done (my router get the PATH and RESV messages) I have the following:

```
R3#show ip rsvp reservation
```

`To          From       Pro   DPort SPort   Next Hop    I/F    Fi   Serv   BPS
123.22.1.2  123.22.2.2  UDP  30001  30000  123.22.1.2   Gi0/0  FF   RATE   7M`

So for me, the router seems to accept the reservation request, but when I send two big data flow (6Mbps) there is no priority flow.
One flow if from 123.22.2.2 to 123.22.1.2 (the priority one) and the second flow is from 123.22.2.3 to 123.22.1.3.
So I'm pretty sure that I'm missing something in my configuration but after several days of research I have still no idea so any help or lead would be appreciated.

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was one missing command into my configuration which is "fair-queue". But this command was unavailable in Cisco release 15.2, I have to downgrade my router in 15.1 in order to make it work.

Here is the interfaces configuration when it works:

`interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 ip address 123.22.1.10 255.255.255.0 
 duplex auto 
 speed 10
 fair-queue
 ip rsvp bandwidth 7500 7500
 ip rsvp resource-provider wfq interface 
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1 
 ip address 123.22.2.20 255.255.255.0 
 duplex auto 
 speed auto 
 ip rsvp bandwidth 1 1
!`

With this donwgrade action, it seems that Cisco will not be able to support IntServ in the future. So a dynamic resources reservation is not a good idea if you use Cisco routers.